# How to change user in .desktop file?

Tags: .desktop

I have a .desktop file whose `Exec=` line I want to be run as another user.  In a *systemd* service file, I can achieve this with a `User=` and `Group=` option.  How to do the same in a .desktop file?

Comment: `systemd` services are run as root, and so can switch user.  Desktop files are run as the calling user, and so can't switch user.  You may want to describe the bigger problem you're trying to solve; that should give you some useful guidance.

Comment: @StephenHarris Yes, I figured out that maybe it was possible to make the desktop file to prompt for superuser password in the GUI to effect the change.  Something like `gksudo` does.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just `gksudo` within the exec line?

Comment: @Fox None.  Apparently, I just needed somebody with better judgement like you to tell me to just try it (doh!).  Exec=gksudo -u wantedUser /path/to/cmd is all I needed.  Thank you for the nudge.